# Are std::vector objects containing boost::optional objects movable? Movable boost::optional?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

```
std::vector<boost::optional<double>> foo;
//populate foo.
```

A vector is movable since the new standard, but unfortunately they haven't made optional movable yet :(

1. Any plans on making optional movable?
2. Will the above vector still be efficiently movable just like any other vector?

Comment: Note that `boost::optional` might never be movable. For a value type, it does not always make sense to move (i.e. if the object is stored by value, there is nothing for which ownership can be transferred to the destination object)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas so i suppose optional is mostly for small, preferably built-in, types right? So an optional vector (if the vector is big) might not be a good idea i guess?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It should support the same move mechanics as the type it contains IMO.  `boost::optional<std::string>` should be movable.

Comment: It depends, it might make perfect sense, but you should be aware that the object copy might be expensive and be explicit in your move operations to move out of the optional object.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That is the *it does not **always** make sense to move*. In some cases it might or might not. The proposal for a `std::optional` [N3406](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3406.html), for example, does support move construction although it might not be the most natural one (a moved-from optional object is still *engaged*, i.e. has a contained object, although that object is *moved*)

Comment: I have a *move-aware* optional (that is, it forwards/moves values where it makes sense). It also means that an `optional<Movable>` is reported as having copy semantics, even though a movable type might not support copy semantics -- this will still be usable as long as the copy operations are not instantiated. I am working on an `optional<T>` that has copy semantics iff `T` also has, and has move semantics only iff `T` also has. It is not particularly hard to implement (nor do I think there is a conceptual hurdle: `optional<T>` 'inherits' the semantics of `T`), but the boilerplate is annoying.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: "*a moved-from optional object is still engaged*" No it isn't. A moved-from optional will be like the rest of the standard-library objects: in a valid but undefined state.

Comment: @NicolBolas: That is a quote from N3406 to tell the author :). In that proposal, the state of `std::optional` after moving offers a stricter guarantee than what is generally required, they guarantee that if the object was engaged, it is still engaged although the stored object is in a *valid but undefined state*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `std::vector` component is movable regardless of the stored type. The move operation just needs to *move* the pointers to the internal buffers in one vector to the other vector. The type of the objects stored in that buffer is irrelevant, as those stay where they are.